# npm install on laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, npm, npm-install

I try to install a few packages listed on a package.json file, with only these dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
  "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "laravel-mix": "^1.0"
}
```

but when I run npm install (in the root folder) it install over 1000 packages  in a node_modules folder, in the root folder.
I guess I m doing something wrong but I really just start with npm, I read that npm will download all dependencies at once but 1000 ones I ve got some doubt (~ 168 Mo)!

Also as these packages are only for development (except jquery but i will link it directly from a cdn after all) maybe I can install them globally ?

Thx for help

I m using npm version 5.5.1 and Laravel 5.4

Comment: Node packages tend to have a lot of dependencies. I've got 6300 in the project I'm working on. Do you have any non-dev dependencies? Those would be included too.

Comment: It works as expected. (laravel-mix has a lot of dependencies) And yes you can install them globally if you think you'll use them for future projects.